# Laravel package route can't find controller class

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a Laravel package using the guidelines of https://laravelpackage.com/.

My package name is `Company/FirstPackage`.

It resides in the `WebSite/packages` folder of a host Laravel application.

In it I have created a controller in `src/Http/Controllers`:

```
    namespace Company\FirstPackage\Controllers;

    class FirstController extends Illuminate\Routing\Controller {
        public function getName() {
            return response()->json('hi, this is name');
        }
    }
```

And I have created a simple `api.php` file in the `WebSite/packages/Company/FirstPackage/route` directory and in it, I have this route:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::get('/name', [Company\FirstPackage\Controllers\FirstController:class, 'getName']);
    Route::get('/testRoute', function() { return 'route is working'; });
```

The `127.0.0.1:8000/testRoute` works as expected. But when I go to `127.0.0.0:8000/name` I get this error:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [Company\FirstPackage\Controllers\FirstController] does not exist.

I have tried all suggestions in [this link](https://litvinjuan.medium.com/how-to-fix-target-class-does-not-exist-in-laravel-8-f9e28b79f8b4):

1. Add the namespace back manually so you can use it as you did in
   Laravel 7.x and before
2. Use the full namespace in your route files when using the
   string-syntax
3. Use the action syntax (recommended)

But non of them worked.

How should I fix this bug?

**Update**: Part of the content of the `composer.json` is as follow:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Company\\FirstPackage\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Company\\FirstPackage\\FirstPackageServiceProvider"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your package's composer.json, it's likely your controller namespace needs to be: `Company\FirstPackage\Http\Controllers` to match the path that the controller is in

Comment: @apokryfos, question updated.

Comment: @Peppermintology, as you see, the second route works. So route registeration is done.

Comment: @apokryfos, is it a rule in PHP and Laravel that class namespaces should match folder hierarchy? Because my controller is in `WebSite\packages\Company\FirstPackage\src\Http\Controllers` folder, but my namespace is `Company\FirstPackage\Controllers`.

Comment: Your package root is in `src` and you give that a namespace of `Company\FirstPackage` (that's what the line under `psr-4` in your composer.json means) therefore a file in `src/Http/Controllers` should have a namespace of `Company\FirstPackage\Http\Controllers` to be [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compliant. The rule is basically from composer which handles the autoloading

Comment: why are you using packages and not vendor through composer? "WebSite\packages" seems wrong

Comment: @mrhn, I'm creating a package generation tool. But also blog posts I read used `packages` folder. Does it differ?

Comment: but arent you installing your package with composer?

Comment: Yeah, but we install them from our local git. And why there are resided inside `packages` folder in the host app, they are submodules of the host app and they would be in their own git repositories, without `packages` or `vendor` folder.